# WebSocket dando erro na criação

Tags: php, websocket

Estou com problema, ao tentar executar o websocket, ele me retorna o seguinte erro na imagem

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

o código que estou usando é este:

```
<?php
$ip = 'localhost';
$porta = 8080;
//-------------------------------
$servidor = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
socket_set_option($servidor, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1);
socket_bind($servidor, $ip, $porta);
socket_listen($servidor);
$cliente = socket_accept($servidor);
//--------------------------------
$pedido = socket_read($cliente, 5000);
preg_match('#Sec-WebSocket-Key: (.*)\r\n#', $pedido, $matches);
$key = base64_encode(pack(
    'H*',
    sha1($matches[1] . '258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11')
));
$headers = "HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\r\n";
$headers .= "Upgrade: websocket\r\n";
$headers .= "Connection: Upgrade\r\n";
$headers .= "Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13\r\n";
$headers .= "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: $key\r\n\r\n";
socket_write($cliente, $headers, strlen($headers));
// mensagem
while (true) {
    sleep(1);
    $content = 'horas: ' . time();
    $response = chr(129) . chr(strlen($content)) . $content;
    socket_write($cliente, $response);
}
?>
```

Obs: estou tentando aprender a usar sozinho kkk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dá até vergonha, mas eu esqueci de habilitar no PHP.ini o "extension=sockets", depois que tirei o ponto e virgula e reiniciei o servidor apache, funcionou normalmente.